# How to use groupby in lambda and call first and last value of same id?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very basic doubt . How to call first and last value of teo column with same id using lambda function?

for example if i have the following data,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["id"] = ['A1','A2','A1','A1','A1','2A','2A','2C','A2','2C'] 
df["Start"] = [ '- 24.432972' ,'-33.94611','48.12358','-108.235678','75.56794','300.235689‌​','-80.26598','55.23‌​4987','208.29574','1‌​01.235689']
df["End"] = ['-12.234859','-78.26574','40.59862','81.265987','78.245798'‌​,'36.159648','-88.22‌​2256','-51.624566','‌​-205.235894','108.23‌​5684']
```

How to groupby id and get the first value and last value of start and end , grouped by id ?

```
 df = df.groupby('id')['Start'].first().apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)

This gives me NaN values as output
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df.groupby('id').agg({'start': 'first', 'end': 'last'})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need first [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and then get max per columns or per rows by [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('id').agg({'start': 'first', 'end': 'last'})
print (df1)
    start end
id           
123     4   1
213     6   6
456     2   8

df2 = df1.max()
print (df2)
start    6.0
end      8.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df3 = df1.max(axis=1)
print (df3)
id
123    4.0
213    6.0
456    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: tnx! if i wanna extract first of start, can i use - df1 = df.groupby('id').agg({'start': 'first''}) and to extract last of end, this : df1 = df.groupby('id').agg({ 'end': 'last'})

Comment: Yes, or simply `df1 = df.groupby('id')['start'].first()` and `df2 = df.groupby('id')['end'].last()`

Comment: i get NaN as output !! i tried converting the datatype object to numeric also

Comment: Hmmm, how do you convert it to int?

Comment: I think you can use `df = df.astype(int)` first.

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '31.143378'

Comment: And what `df = df.astype(float)` ?

Comment: I get NaN as output again !! :/ i have values like -  24.432972 , -33.94611

Comment: And how work, try `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)` - It replace bad non numeric to NaN, and by `fillna` to `0` ?

Comment: it gets converted to float64 but still NaN ! i couldnt figure out why !! i tried individually also ! df2 = df.groupby('id')['end'].last().apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(float) & print df2

Comment: Can you create new question with your code, input data and desired output? Because I think it is hard find solution without data. Thanks.

Comment: The website doesnt allow me to create a new question. Do you want me to edit the question here or enter my sample data in the comment section ???

Comment: df["id"] = ['A1','A2','A1','A1','A1','2A','2A','2C','A2','2C']
df["Start"] = [ '- 24.432972' ,'-33.94611','48.12358','-108.235678','75.56794','300.235689','-80.26598','55.234987','208.29574','101.235689']
df["End"] = ['-12.234859','-78.26574','40.59862','81.265987','78.245798','36.159648','-88.222256','-51.624566','-205.235894','108.235684']

Comment: df = df.groupby('id')['Start'].first().apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)

Comment: it gives NaN values

Comment: Ok, so first if have only `df1 = df.groupby('id')['Start'].first()` what return `print (df1)` ? NaN values?

Comment: Ok, I think you need first step `df["Start"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Start"], errors='coerce')` and `df["End"] = pd.to_numeric(df["End"], errors='coerce')` and then use `df1 = df.groupby('id')['start'].first()` and `df2 = df.groupby('id')['end'].last()`

Comment: can i do , df = pd.to_numeric(df[['Start','End'']],errors='coerce') ??

Comment: No, need `df = df[['Start','End'']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce') `